# "Could not start the command." Error message Ubuntu TeXmaker

Tags: errors

I've been having some technical issues with LaTeX lately. I'm using Ubuntu and I'm trying to make a LaTeX file. Here's my code:
[image]
     When I press the arrow to the left of "quick build" I get:
[image]
     What's going on? Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please paste your code into your question rather than posting screenshots. Then highlight the code and hit the `{}` button to format it. That will be a lot more readable and a lot easier to work with than pictures of your screen ;). Thanks.

Comment: it seems that TexMaker isn't configured with your `TeX` distribution. (I suppose that `Texlive`)

Comment: You should verify to have installed texlive, in fact ubuntu has a minimal installation, TeXmaker should works.

Answer (score 3):

Just install the relevant packages from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
```

That will get you a basic LaTeX system. For a more complete installation with more packages and fonts, use this:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended
```

for XeLatex

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
```

Now you can compile all!

Comment: `apt install texlive-xetex` is compatible for TexStudio also. This enabled me to compile with `xelatex` for an `.xtx` file in TexStudio. Thanks.